# Export NDSolve output to .txt

Tags: differential-equations, export

I tried to store the output of the following piece of code

```
s = NDSolve[{u'[x] ==  v[x] , v'[x] == u[x], u[0] == 1, 
    v[0] == 1}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 70, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 20] ;
```

in a `.txt` file with the commands

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Table[{x, u[x] /. s, v[x] /. s}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}] // TableForm
Export["data.txt", data, "List"];
```

Unfortunately the resulting `.txt` had the following ugly arrangement

```
0.{1.}{1.}
0.1{1.1051709180440972}{1.1051709180440972}
0.2{1.2214027580171631}{1.2214027580171631}
0.30000000000000004{1.349858807431976}{1.349858807431976}
0.4{1.4918246976372467}{1.4918246976372467}
0.5{1.648721270402639}{1.648721270402639}
0.6000000000000001{1.8221187976152273}{1.8221187976152273}
0.7000000000000001{2.013752707127757}{2.013752707127757}
0.8{2.2255409261449164}{2.2255409261449164}
0.9{2.4596031083207683}{2.4596031083207683}
1.{2.718281828459045}{2.718281828459045}
```

I want to get something like this

```
0.0    1.00000  1.00000
0.1    1.10517  1.10517
0.2    1.22140  1.22140 
0.3    1.34985  1.34985 
...
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: The biggest problem is that you included the wrapper `TableForm` in the definition of `data`. Wrappers such as `TableForm` are intended for display purposes only. Isolate the definition of `data` from its display formatting by using parentheses, i.e., `(data = Table[{x, u[x] /. s, v[x] /. s}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]) // TableForm`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to get something like this

Well, I think it is better to export the data as is, i.e. without chopping it. Let the client who reads the file later on decide if they need less accuracy. So you could save it as

```
data = Table[Flatten@{x, u[x] /. s, v[x] /. s}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}];
Export["data.txt", data, "TSV"]
```

This gives

```
0.  1.  1.
0.1 1.1051709180440972  1.1051709180440972
0.2 1.2214027580171631  1.2214027580171631
0.30000000000000004 1.349858807431976   1.349858807431976
0.4 1.4918246976372467  1.4918246976372467
0.5 1.648721270402639   1.648721270402639
0.6000000000000001  1.8221187976152273  1.8221187976152273
0.7000000000000001  2.013752707127757   2.013752707127757
0.8 2.2255409261449164  2.2255409261449164
0.9 2.4596031083207683  2.4596031083207683
1.  2.718281828459045   2.718281828459045
```

If you want to chop the numbers down, say for 6 decimal places before exporting, this can also be easily done before exporting. But I do not think it is good idea myself.